# How to set an instance property with two numerical variables

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, object, properties

I'm trying to figure out how to use the two variables `arect` and `declin` to define the `target` property inside the `aladin` instance. The `target` property needs the two numerical values separated by a ",".

How do I ensure that the target can read the coordinates I stored in the two variables.

The ajax request is made every 10 seconds and it stores different variables each time.

```
var arect = {};
var declin = {};
$.ajax({
    url: "getstatus2.php", 
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        arect = data.ar;
        declin = data.dec;
        console.log(arect);
        console.log(declin);
    }
});

var aladin = A.aladin('#aladin-lite-div1', {
    survey: "P/allWISE/color", 
    fov:1,
    cooFrame:"ICRS",
    showReticle:"true",
    showFrame:"true",
    showLayersControl:"false",
    showZoomControl:"true",
    target:'arect,declin',
});
```

Comment: I didn't get your question but what happens when a request takes longer than 10 seconds? Maybe you should add a logical clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your target as such:

```
target: arect + ',' + declin
```

However, you need to set this as a result of your ajax call. Either you move this entire block starting with `var aladin = A.aladin ...` into the `success` block. Or you create a function to set your aladin variable.

For example:

```
function SetAladin(arect, declin) {
var aladin = A.aladin('#aladin-lite-div1', {
    survey: "P/allWISE/color", 
    fov:1,
    cooFrame:"ICRS",
    showReticle:"true",
    showFrame:"true",
    showLayersControl:"false",
    showZoomControl:"true",
    target: arect + ',' + declin,
    });
}
```

and then in your `success` block, just call the function.

```
SetAladin(data.ar, data.dec);
```